# Struts2 Infinite recursion detected

Tags: java, recursion, model-view-controller, struts2, action

I have a struts2 chain result that redirects to itself but it does NOT create an infinite loop because there is a condition that will eventually evaluate to false and then the recursion will stop. I have to use chain instead of redirectAction because I need a POST request which redirectAction cannot do.

This is the exception I'm getting

```
Could not execute action
Infinite recursion detected: [/view/myAction!myMethod, /view/myAction, /view/myAction] - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionChainResult.execute(ActionChainResult.java:214)
```

I have been through the xwork jar where the infinite loop detection is based. It looks at the chain history and if it finds the action name it throws an exception. The maximum recursion is hardcoded to 1.

Is there a way to handle the exception or increase the maximum number of allowed recursions or reset the chain history manually while chaining?

Comment: An action *chained* to *itself* that uses a business variable to detect when to chain or to break ? It sounds like an amazing recipe for a disaster. Rethink the whole operation. Don't chain/redirect to itself, don't chain at all, and don't use POST, use POST / REDIRECT / GET. If you need common logic that is in the action, extract that logic and put it in a business component, outside of the action, then call it from all the actions you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to manipulate the chain history from an interceptor

```
    final ActionContext context = invocation.getInvocationContext();
    LinkedList<String> chainHistory = (LinkedList<String>) context.get("CHAIN_HISTORY");
    // context.put("CHAIN_HISTORY", null);
```